# Python BeautifulSoup not extracting every URL

Tags: python, url, beautifulsoup, extract

I'm trying to find all the URLs on this page: https://courses.students.ubc.ca/cs/courseschedule?pname=subjarea&tname=subj-all-departments

More specifically, **I want the links that are hyperlinked under each "Subject Code"**. However, when I run my code, barely any links get extracted.

I would like to know why this is happening, and how I can fix it.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://courses.students.ubc.ca/cs/courseschedule?pname=subjarea&tname=subj-all-departments"

page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, features="lxml")

for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(link.get('href'))
```

This is my first attempt in web-scraping..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's an anti-bot protection, just add a user-agent to your headers. and do not forget to check your soup when things go wrong

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://courses.students.ubc.ca/cs/courseschedule?pname=subjarea&tname=subj-all-departments"
ua={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; PPC Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/531.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.869.0 Safari/531.2'}
r = requests.get(url, headers=ua)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, features="lxml")

for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(link.get('href'))
```

the message in the soup was

> ##### Sorry for the inconvenience.
>
> We have detected excess or unusual web requests originating from your browser, and are unable to determine whether these requests are automated.
>
> To proceed to the requested page, please complete the captcha below.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `nth-child(1)` to restrict to the first column of the table matched by id. Then simply extract the `.text`. If that contains `*` then provide a default string for no course offered, otherwise, concatenate the retrieved course identifier onto a base query string construct:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
r = requests.get('https://courses.students.ubc.ca/cs/courseschedule?pname=subjarea&tname=subj-all-departments', headers=headers)
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
no_course = ''
base = 'https://courses.students.ubc.ca/cs/courseschedule?pname=subjarea&tname=subj-department&dept='
course_info = {i.text:(no_course if '*' in i.text else base + i.text) for i in soup.select('#mainTable td:nth-child(1)')}
course_info
```